# Search option in Update Manager

Tags: 11.10, updates, update-manager, search

I rarely use Update manager and when ever I use it, I don't update everything, just a few programs which I use more frequently.

For selecting a update of a program I have to scroll through a huge list of updates.

Is there any option for searching for a specific update(s)?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you just want to update firefox out of all other updates.
Then just type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

It will install only firefox update, leaving the others.

Comment: +1 Thanks for an alternative. But still I'm looking for an option in update manager.

Comment: hope you find it... i would like to see it too